# Cifrado AES cliente servidor

Tags: java, cifrado

Necesito consultar acerca del uso del cifrado AES, en mi caso tengo una aplicación muy sencilla cliente-servidor donde se envían datos (una cadena) cifrados desde el cliente, y el servidor (en local)  los decodifica y los muestra en un JTextArea. Entiendo que hay algoritmos mejor recomendados para esta labor pero quería saber si es posible hacerlo de todas formas. Alguien me puede explicar como hacer para que pueda desencriptar el string recibido, o si necesito utilizar otras clases? Me da un error javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher, que esta relacionado con la longitud de la clave pero no se como lograr que funcione.

Dejo el código:

CLIENTE:

```
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                Socket miSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.18",9999);                  
                DataOutputStream flujo_salida = new DataOutputStream(miSocket.getOutputStream());
        
                //***********************************CIFRADO INPUT:
                KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");          
                kg.init(128);
                SecretKey clave= kg.generateKey();
            
                Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clave);
                
                byte texto_Plano[] = txtField.getText().getBytes();         
                byte texto_Cifrado[] = c.doFinal(texto_Plano);              
                //******FIN CIFRADO****************************************
                System.out.println("CLIENTE =  "+new String(texto_Cifrado));
                flujo_salida.writeUTF(new String(texto_Cifrado));                   
                flujo_salida.close();                   
                
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadPaddingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
      });
```

SERVIDOR:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
            String codificado = txtArea.getText();
            
            try {
                System.out.println(codificado);

                KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");                  
                SecretKey clave= kg.generateKey();
            
                Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clave);
                
                byte texto_Cifrado[] = c.doFinal(codificado.getBytes());
                System.out.println("SERVIDOR = "+new String(texto_Cifrado));
                
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
        
        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿Por qué "enviar la clave al servidor"? Si usas AES es porque se trata de criptografía simétrica, ¿no? En criptografía simétrica el intercambio o distribución de claves se debe hacer a través de un canal seguro antes de que las partes se puedan comunicar.

Comment: Ahi puse el codigo del lado servidor, el error que me da no tiene que ver con la clave: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher .  o si ?

Comment: Creo que deberías mejorar la pregunta. Si lo que te interesa es resolver la IllegalBlockSizeException, deberías poner el stack trace completo e indicar en qué línea ocurre. Consulta [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar la probabilidad de conseguir ayuda.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, lo he corregido para que se entienda mejor, disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía errores en el desencriptado ya que el tamaño del bloque AES es siempre de 128 bits, debe recibir entradas en múltiplos de este número. La entrada más pequeña debe rellenarse a 16 bytes y el tipo de relleno debe especificarse en el algoritmo. fuente: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890592/javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-input-length-not-multiple-of-16-bytes)

Solución: Usar:   "AES / CBC / PKCS5Padding".

Dejo el código:

```
  public class Principal {

       private static String algoritmo = "AES";

          public static void main(String[] args) {

             new Cliente();        //--> implementa encriptar()
             new Servidor();       //--> implementa desencriptar()
            
       
}

 private static SecretKeySpec crearClave() {
     
     byte[] claveEncriptacion = algoritmo.getBytes("UTF-8");
         
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
         
        claveEncriptacion = sha.digest(claveEncriptacion);
        claveEncriptacion = Arrays.copyOf(claveEncriptacion, 16);
         
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(claveEncriptacion,algoritmo);
 
        return secretKey;
    }
 
 public static String encriptar(String datos) {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = crearClave();
         
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");        
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
 
        byte[] datosEncriptar = datos.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] bytesEncriptados = cipher.doFinal(datosEncriptar);
        String encriptado = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytesEncriptados);
 
        return encriptado;
    }
 
 
 public static String desencriptar(String datosEncriptados) {

        SecretKeySpec secretKey = crearClave();
 
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
         
        byte[] bytesEncriptados = Base64.getDecoder().decode(datosEncriptados);
        byte[] datosDesencriptados = cipher.doFinal(bytesEncriptados);
        String datos = new String(datosDesencriptados);
         
        return datos;
    }
```

}